# What is wrong with my SQL Insert code?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm struggling with trying to find out why this code isn't working for me. I have tables: `albums (albumid, albumname)`, `composers (composerid, composername)` and `tracks (trackid, tracktitle, albumid, composerid)`.

When I use my form to add a track and link it to a composer and an album from this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<p>Enter the new track:<br />
<textarea name="tracktitle" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea></p>
<p>Composer:    <select name="cid" size="1">
<option selected value="">Select One</option>
<option value="">---------</option>
<?php     while ($composer= mysql_fetch_array($composers)) {
 $cid = $composer['composerid'];
 $cname = htmlspecialchars($composer['composername']);
 echo "<option value='$cid'>$cname</option>\n";} ?>
 </select></p>
 <p>Place in albums:<br />
 <?php      while ($alb = mysql_fetch_array($albs)) {
  $aid = $alb['albumid'];
  $aname = htmlspecialchars($alb['albumname']);
  echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='albs[]' 
  value='$aid' />$aname</label><br />\n";
  } ?>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

I get this message:

> New track added
>   Error inserting track into album 2:
>   Track was added to 0 albums.

The php code that precedes the form is:

```
if (isset($_POST['tracktitle'])): 
 // A new track has been entered
 // using the form.
$tracktitle = mysql_real_escape_string($tracktitle);
$cid= $_POST['cid'];
$tracktitle = $_POST['tracktitle'];
$albs = $_POST['albs'];
if ($cid == '') {
exit('<p>You must choose an composer for this track. Click
```

"Back" and try again.

');}

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tracks (tracktitle)
 VALUES ('$tracktitle')" ;
if (@mysql_query($sql)) {
echo '<p>New track added</p>';
 } else {
exit('<p>Error adding new track' . mysql_error() . '</p> 
echo mysql_error() ');}
$trackid = mysql_insert_id();
if (isset($_POST['albs'])) {
$albs = $_POST['albs'];
} else {
$albs = array();
}
$numAlbs = 0;
foreach ($albs as $albID) {
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tracks (trackid, albumid, 
composerid) VALUES " .
"($trackid, $albs, $cid)";
if ($ok) {
  $numAlbs = $numAlbs + 1;
} else {
  echo "<p>Error inserting track into album $albID: " .
      mysql_error() . '</p>';    }}?>
<p>Track was added to <?php echo $numAlbs; ?> albums.</p>

<?php
else: // Allow the user to enter a new track
$composers = @mysql_query('SELECT composerid, composername 
FROM composers');
if (!$composers) {
 exit('<p>Unable to obtain composer list from the database.</p>');
}
$albs = @mysql_query('SELECT albumid, albumname FROM albums');
if (!$albs) {
  exit('<p>Unable to obtain album list from the database.</p>');}?>
```

I keep searching for why this is failing and I keep hitting brick walls. I also know that at present it's not very secure which will be the next thing I sort out. I just want to get the actual function working first.

Comment: You are still using brain-dead string manipulation for SQL. There is no point addressing any other issues until this is fixed IMOHO, as in fixing this fundamental flaw -- and understanding *why* it is a flaw -- is a crucial step to a better development process. And yes, your code is vulnerable to attack.

Comment: Give your code some love. My head explodes when I try to read that mess.

Comment: Some pretty harsh comments here... He did acknowledge the code is insecure and say "I just want to get the actual function working first", guys. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@paj: Change

```
if ($ok) {
```

to

```
if (mysql_query($sql)) {
```

-

I also suggest you update your SQL statements to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tracks (tracktitle) VALUES ('" . $tracktitle . "')";

$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tracks (trackid, albumid, composerid) VALUES (" . $trackid . ", " . $albID . ", " . $cid . ")";
```

Comment: I don't mind harsh comments so much. I do find some comments more helpful than others. Thanks for your help. I see the Values in my Insert code were just the names of the table fields. I've changed it to what you suggested. Though I don't get the error message after adding a new track, looking at the tracks table I see the new tracktitle listed but the albumid and composerid are at 0.  Will investigate further. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like `$ok` doesn't exist except in the `if ($ok) {`
line. It needs to be defined somewhere prior, otherwise it will always read false because it doesn't exist.

Actually you can skip the $ok which doesn't exist and put in `if (@mysql_query($sql)) {` for that line like you have above. I do have to agree with the comments that the code needs some love, but if you want to know why it's breaking down, it appears this is why.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I started with tutorials/books and then adapted one for my own project to try and understand how it works. I guess that's why I overlook bits like this. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Good luck learning. Since you are a new stackoverflow user, you should also start off on the right foot here by "accepting" whichever answer is most helpful. Glad we could help.